# How do I disable magic quotes on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, quotes

How can I get my excerpts on my wordpress site to stop adding these slashes? I'm calling `get_the_excerpt();` and have tried calling `wp_filter_nohtml_kses(the_excerpt())` and `stripslashes(the_excerpt())` but am still getting the same slashes to my excerpts. I've also tried making a filter to keep the quotes from being added but still didn't change anything:

```
function remove_slashes( $excerpt ) {
    return stripslashes( wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $excerpt ) );
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'remove_slashes' );
```

Any time there's a single or double quote, a slash is being added to the front of the quote. In my research I've learned that they're Magic Quotes from PHP, but using stripslashes has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stripslashes_deep()`

```
function remove_slashes( $excerpt ) {
    return stripslashes_deep( $excerpt );
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'remove_slashes' );
```

Comment: This works! Now calling echo '<p>'. get_the_excerpt() .'</p>' is showing quotes without slashes. Thanks Bhautik!

Comment: Welcome... glad to be of help.